# Is an analytical, linear and bounded map between dual spaces Y* and X* defined on bounded domains weak*-weak* continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $\Omega=(0,1)^2$ and $\Gamma = \{0\} \times (0,1)$ and be $v:L^{\infty}(\Gamma_2) \mapsto L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ given explicitly by $v(u(x_2)) = b(x_1,x_2) u(x_2)$. Is $v$ $weak^*-weak^*$ continuous?

Does the following reasoning makes sense?

Assuming $u_{n} \stackrel{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} u $ in $L^{\infty}(\Gamma_2)$, I want to prove that $v(u_{n}) \stackrel{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} v(u) $ in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. Let $f \in L^{1}(\Omega)$ then:

$\int_{\Omega} \Big(v(u_n)-v(u)\Big) f d\Omega = \int_{\Omega} \,  \, \Big(u_n(x_2)-u(x_2)\Big)b(x_1,x_2) f(x_1,x_2) d\Omega \\= \int_{\Gamma_2} \,  \, \Big(u_n(x_2)-u(x_2)\Big)\Big(\int_{\Gamma_1} b(x_1,x_2) f(x_1,x_2) dx_1\Big) dx_2 \\ = \int_{\Gamma_2} \,  \, \Big(u_n(x_2)-u(x_2)\Big) \tilde{f}(x_2) dx_2 = 0 $

since $\tilde{f}(x_2) = \int_{\Gamma_1} b(x_1,x_2) f(x_1,x_2) dx_1 \in L^{1}(\Gamma_2) $ , thanks to Fubini's theorem.

Comment: You need to add assumptions on $b$. The idea is correct.

Comment: $b$ is analytic, something like $b(x_1,x_2) = e^{-x_1} x_2$